# Sum of PSD an indefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that the symmetric matrix $A$ is PSD and that the symmetric matrix $B$ is indefinite. Is there any condition for which the matrix $A+B$ is PSD?

I'm trying to characterize the Hessian matrix at the convergence point of an algorithm I'm developing. Sadly, the literature on the eigenvalues of sum of matrices is very limited. I tried to bound the minimal eigenvalue of $A+B$ from below and from above in hope that it would turn into something interesting, but it didn't got me very far.

My intuition says that as long as the minimal eigenvalue of $B$ is not "too negative", then the sum will be PSD. Is there any paper that deals with this kind of situation? Any clue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ necessarily symmetric in this context? If so, one sufficient condition is that $\lambda_{\min}(A) \geq -\lambda_{\min}(B)$. However, this only leads to something useful if $A$ is potentially strictly positive definite.

Comment: Yes, both matrices are symmetric. I've edited the question. Thanks!
Unfortunately, the minimal eigenvalue of $A$ can be $0$ (which is more likely in my settings). Can one say something useful in this case?

Comment: Not without more information